# Centring children of Relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

My relative layout consists of two images and i want to centre the children of layout such that two images appear in centre side by side adjusting to different screen sizes.For that i tried adding android:layout_gravity="center" and android:gravity="centre" but it doesn't seem to work.Images appear on the left side.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/muteAudio"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/signInWithFacebook"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/fb_login_selector"

        android:visibility="visible"





  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/signInWithGooglePlus"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/gp_login_selector"

       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/signInWithFacebook"

        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try this android:gravity="center" in two child view

Comment: Why don't you use `LinearLayout` ??

Comment: As @AnshulTyagi said, `LinearLayout` will be better choice for you needs.

Comment: @ user3684678 accept answer which one helped you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes In Your Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/muteAudio"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/signInWithFacebook"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/fb_login_selector"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/signInWithGooglePlus"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/gp_login_selector />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `android:gravity="center"` in two child view

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your view which you want to place in center of layout.

Use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to place view horizontally center

and

Use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` to place view vertically center

Try this :

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/muteAudio"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginBottom="45dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/signInWithFacebook"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/fb_login_selector"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/signInWithGooglePlus"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/signInWithFacebook"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/gp_login_selector" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out like this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="your_drawable" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="your_drawable" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.  Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_above="@+id/muteAudio"
android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/signInWithFacebook"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:margin="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/fb_login_selector"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/signInWithGooglePlus"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:margin="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/gp_login_selector" />
```

If you want the images width change proportionally with screen width, you change:

`android:layout_width="140dp"`

for this:

`android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_height="0.5" //change this value if u want`

If you want, modify margins or padding to add space to layout childs